# How to use OCaml libraries in Swift?

Tags: swift, ocaml

I have a library developed in OCaml.
I need to call functions of the library from my Swift code.

Is it possible to do?
How?

Comment: You'll probably have to go through C. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just googled. I found that I can call C from Swift, and can call Ocaml from C. As the solution I have only one idea (I think that you mean this idea): Create C wrapper for my Ocaml library and use it within Swift code. I didn't try it, I am new in Swift and want to research more (that's why I asked the current question) before starting to develop in this complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

I would go through C. Not sure how the FFI is working on swift's side. For the OCaml side, the easiest solution I can think of is to use ctypes reverse bindings. It can turn some OCaml code into a C library. There is an example here: https://github.com/yallop/ocaml-ctypes-inverted-stubs-example

Ctypes project is hosted there: https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes